# Change text color in UITableViewCell following event happened

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have tableview that contains video program lists. When I tap on a program, that program will be played on player view above that tableview. It looks like this.

[image]

What I want to do is after I tap a row I want text in that row to turn Red color. My problem is it cannot turn Red instantly but I have to scroll the tableview for that row to go off screen and come back on screen again then the text in that selected row will become Red. I know this is behavior of tableview **cellForRowAtIndexPath**. So I add `[self.tableView reloadData]` in tableview **didSelectRowAtIndexPath** but it doesn't work. As I said I have to scroll that selected roll off screen then come back on screen in order to change its color. How can I resolve that problem?

Here below is related code.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
   static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"LiveTableViewCell";

   LiveTableViewCell *cell = (LiveTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

   //...... (more stuff here but not related)

   //Color - for one selected/playing
   if (programList.programId == self.liveData.programId ) {
      [str1 addAttribute:NSStrikethroughColorAttributeName value:[CustomColor textColorf45160] range:strRange1]; //red color
      [str1 addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:[CustomColor textColorf45160] range:strRange1]; //red color
    }

    cell.title.attributedText = str1;

    return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

   //...... (more stuff here but not related)
   [self.tableView reloadData];  
}
```

Comment: From what I noticed you did not set your cell color by checking its indexPath but with some other values you defined and update. Could the codes that update those IDs run after tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest thing to do is to extract the logic that configures the cell into it's own method. Then your cellForRowAtIndexPath and didSelect methods can call through to the same method

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
   static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"LiveTableViewCell";

   LiveTableViewCell *cell = (LiveTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

   //...... (more stuff here but not related)
   [self configureCell:cell withProgramList:programList];

    return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

   //...... (more stuff here but not related)

   LiveTableViewCell *cell = (id)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
   ProgramList *programList = // get programList at indexpath
   [self configureCell:cell withProgramList:programList];
}

- (void)configureCell:(LiveTableViewCell *)cell withProgramList:(ProgramList *)programList {
   //Color - for one selected/playing
   if (programList.programId == self.liveData.programId ) {
      [str1 addAttribute:NSStrikethroughColorAttributeName value:[CustomColor textColorf45160] range:strRange1]; //red color
      [str1 addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:[CustomColor textColorf45160] range:strRange1]; //red color
    }

    cell.title.attributedText = str1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your 'self.tableView' should be same with the 'tableView' in 'didSelectRowAtIndexPath'.

Answer (score 0):

You can use - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
didHighlightRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath delegate function like this:

```
(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
didHighlightRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

  LiveTableViewCell *cell = (LiveTableViewCell *)[tableView    cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
  cell.title.textColor = UIColor.redColor;


}
```